Increasing The Limits On POSIX Message Queues
I am running a process in Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL), where I am trying to communicate with windows processes. In the process, many mailboxes are required and extensive communication is expected.
At a further point in my code, I am getting the error: Too many open files while mq_open is called.
I have tried increasing the limits in the files mentioned in mq_overview :

/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max

/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/queues_max


But I am not able to open message queues with large sizes(more than 80) . I have tried increasing the limits before running my executable in WSL by command ulimit -n and ulimit -q but it doesn't work.
Also , I have tried the solutions proposed by existing answers, but I can't find a way to open large number of queues with more number of messages.

Seems like a flawed design.  Can't you just use multiple message types with a few queues?

@TimRoberts , sorry but it is not possible. Code has been designed by some architect decades ago and communication is not happening between 3 or 4 threads but there are more than 100 threads involved.
